# How to show that $f$ is an injective complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Basically all I know is $f$ is analytic in $D = \{z: |z-z_0| < R\}$.
and that $|f'(z) - f'(z_0)| < |f'(z_0)|$ for every $z \in D$.

One can deduce that $f'(z) \neq 0$ for every $z \in D$. but it appears to be not strong enough, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write

$$f(w_1) - f(w_0) = \int_{w_0}^{w_1} f'(z)\,dz = \int_{w_0}^{w_1} f'(z_0)\,dz - \int_{w_0}^{w_1} \bigl(f'(z_0) - f'(z)\bigr)\,dz.\tag{1}$$

Now you can look whether you see how to employ the given inequality.

Taking the modulus in $(1)$ and applying the [reverse] triangle inequality, we see

\begin{align}
\lvert f(w_1) - f(w_0)\rvert &= \biggl\lvert \int_{w_0}^{w_1} f'(z_0)\,dz - \int_{w_0}^{w_1} \bigl(f'(z_0) - f'(z)\bigr)\,dz\biggr\rvert \\
&\geqslant \biggl\lvert \int_{w_0}^{w_1} f'(z_0)\,dz\biggr\rvert - \biggl\lvert \int_{w_0}^{w_1} \bigl(f'(z_0) - f'(z)\bigr)\,dz\biggr\rvert\\
&= \lvert f'(z_0)\rvert\cdot \lvert w_1 - w_0\rvert - \biggl\lvert \int_{w_0}^{w_1} \bigl(f'(z_0) - f'(z)\bigr)\,dz\biggr\rvert\\
&= \lvert f'(z_0)\rvert\cdot \lvert w_1 - w_0\rvert - \biggl\lvert \int_0^1 \bigl(f'(z_0) - f'(w_0 + t(w_1-w_0))\bigr)\cdot (w_1 - w_0)\,dt\biggr\rvert\\
&\geqslant \lvert f'(z_0)\rvert\cdot\lvert w_1 - w_0\rvert - \int_0^1 \lvert f'(z_0) - f'(w_0 + t(w_1-w_0))\rvert\,dt \cdot \lvert w_1 - w_0\rvert\\
&= \int_0^1 \bigl(\lvert f'(z_0)\rvert - \lvert f'(z_0) - f'(w_0 + t(w_1-w_0))\rvert\bigr)\,dt \cdot \lvert w_1 - w_0\rvert.
\end{align}

Comment: You mean equality?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But I still have a problem , I cannot put $| |$ inside the integral because $|\int_{a}^{b} f| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |f| $

Comment: @Gary. No, the inequality $\lvert f'(z_0) - f'(z)\rvert < \lvert f'(z_0)\rvert$.

Comment: @d_e Use $\lvert a-b\rvert \geqslant \lvert a\rvert - \lvert b\rvert$.

Comment: tried.. but still , same problem.

Comment: @d_e Can you see it now?

Comment: yes, I think so. thanks. However, I'm pretty sure there should more elegant way of solving this. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @d_e No! He _gave_ the elegant solution. I can't imagine how a solution could be simpler or clearer. Maybe you're missing the elegance because he wrote down all those little details. The "elegant" version (or the version you'd see in a paper or something) is just this: "Note that 
$$f(w_1) - f(w_0) = \int_{w_0}^{w_1} f'(z_0)\,dz - \int_{w_0}^{w_1} \bigl(f'(z_0) - f'(z)\bigr)\,dz."$$

Comment: you right david. I was later thinking on this. that's indeed a very elegant solution. I was anticipating using a key theorem. so somewhat surprised to see it this solution.