# Complex function’s injection(solve it please......)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z| |z-z_0|<1\}$
If $f$ is analytic function on $D$ and $|f’(z)-f’(z_0)|<|f’(z_0)|$,
Then $f$ is injective

First, I’m sorry
This is my first time to use this page
So, I want to solve this question.
I heard this question is very hard
But I believe you can solve it.
I have been studying Complex analsis
I spent time to solve this question
I couldn’t prove this question..
Please answer me, How to solve it?

Comment: This isn't my forte, but I know generally it's helpful to give a bit of detail on what you were thinking/how you were attacking the problem. This helps us not go down blind alleys or provide good feedback on your method. Would you mind sharing your work?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1356460/42969.

Answer (score 0):

Assume wlog $z_0=0$ (change variables $z-z_0=w$) and rotate and scale s.t $f'(0)=1$ (this doesn't change injectivity or lack of it); then the condition becomes $|f'(z)-1|<1$ for all $|z|<1$  and that implies $\Re f'(z) >0$  (since $|a-1|<1$ implies by squaring $|a|^2-2\Re a <0$).

But now the unit disc is convex so the easy Noshiro Warschavski theorem ([discussed here in other posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354390/positive-real-part-of-derivative-imply-injectivity/3354444#3354444) and obtained by integration on segments) applies so $f$ is injective

Comment: Please Let me show If |a-1|<1 then |a|^2-2Re(a)<0

Comment: square the inequality so you get: $1>|a-1|^2=(a-1)(\bar a -1)=|a|^2+1-2\Re a$

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

From the statement it follows that, on the disk, $f’$ doesn’t vanish.

But we can actually state more: define on the disk $g(z)=f’(z_0)(z-z_1)$; then $|(f-f(z_1))’-g’| < |g’|$. Since $(f-f(z_1))(z_1)=g(z_1)=0$, and since $g’$ is constant, we can integrate and it follows $|(f-f(z_1))-g| < |g|$.

So by Rouché, in any disk of $D$, $f-f(z_1)$ and $g$ have the same number of roots. As a consequence, $\{f=f(z_1)\}=\{z_1\}$.

Edit: in answer to your comment, the result is the following. Let $U$ be a convex open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f,g$ be holomorphic functions on $U$ such that $g$ is affine, $|f’| < |g’|$ and for some $p$ in $U$, $f(p)=g(p)=0$. Then, everywhere in $U$ except at $p$, $|f| < |g|$.

Proof: let $z \in U$, $z \neq p$, $$|f(z)|=\left|(z-p)\int_0^1{f’((1-t)p+tz)\,dt}\right|=|z-p|\int_0^1{|f’((1-t)p+tz)|\,dt} < |z-p|\int_0^1{|g’((1-t)p+tz)/,dt}=|z-p|\left|\int_0^1{g’((1-t)p+tz)\,dt}\right|=|g(z)|.$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: How to assure If |f’-g’|<|g’|, then |f-g|<|g|?

Comment: I don’t vote down Someone vote down